# Another about XPath structure with SoapUI and Property Transfer - nested repeated tags

Tags: testing, xpath, properties, soapui, transfer

Yet another problem. 
This time I think because the tag is used twice in the same message, nested.

I have no issue retrieving other items with unique labels (like `requestDateTime`, `statusDateTime` and `completedStateEnteredDate`), but I can't successfully grab the `<som>` reference number, or the status (which is inside status) or the type (again, inside another `<type>` tag).

So I know my namespace works, just can't work out how to get the data I need.
Specifically, I need to capture that numeric value in the `<som>6000526</som>` part. The data does return multiple SOM numbers, so the bonus would be how do I capture more than one (like the first 2 or 5 would be cool).

```
<return>
    <success>true</success>
    <networkUpdateList>
       <confirmationDue>
          <actualDays>26</actualDays>
          <actualHours>11</actualHours>
          <actualMinutes>57</actualMinutes>
          <businessDays>22</businessDays>
          <businessHours>7</businessHours>
          <businessMinutes>57</businessMinutes>
          <negative>true</negative>
       </confirmationDue>
       <confirmingCarrierId>11567</confirmingCarrierId>
       <numbers>
          <donorCarrierId>11657</donorCarrierId>
          <gainingCarrierId>11667</gainingCarrierId>
          <losingCarrierId>11657</losingCarrierId>
          <number>
             <phoneNumber>098453520</phoneNumber>
          </number>
       </numbers>
       <som>
          <requestDateTime>2017-04-11T10:08:01+12:00</requestDateTime>
          <som>6000526</som>
          <status>
             <status>GC and LC Complete</status>
          </status>
          <statusDateTime>2017-04-11T10:09:09+12:00</statusDateTime>
          <type>
             <type>Port</type>
          </type>
          <completedStateEnteredDate>2017-04-11T10:09:09+12:00</completedStateEnteredDate>
       </som>
    </networkUpdateList>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I staggered upon the solution, works for all duplicated names:
//som/som does the job.
As does //status/status and //type/type so I am a happy camper.
I just don't know how to pick up the next occurrence within the response, but I don't desperately need that, I can just loop.
Edit: Also discovered that
`(//som/som) [2]`
Returns the second occurence, and that (//som/som) [1] returns the first, etc. Very simple and good to know.
Discovered here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Use this XPath expression to get the result desired:

```
/return/networkUpdateList/som/som
```

**Result:**

```
<som>6000526</som>
```

This even works for multiple `<som>` element children of different `networkUpdateList` nodes.

Comment: I did try that, tried it again, still returns [null]. I should add that /return/networkUpdateList/som/requestDateTime also returns [null] but //requestDateTime returns the expected value of  2017-04-11T10:09:09+12:00 but because (I think because) there is a <som> within a <som> the //som option fails.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Script assertion and use the following code:

```
// create groovyUtils and XmlHolder for response of Request 1 request
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context )
def holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder( "SOAP Request#Response" )

// loop item nodes in response message
for( item in holder.getNodeValues( "//som/som" ))
    log.info "Item : [$item]"
```

This should print out all the values for each node that that follows the XPath. In the script Assertion Log should output in the following format:

> Wed Mar 21 14:46:14 GMT 2018:INFO:Item : [0.69]
>
> Wed Mar 21 14:46:14 GMT 2018:INFO:Item : [4.14]
>
> Wed Mar 21 14:46:14 GMT 2018:INFO:Item : [0.69]
>
> Wed Mar 21 14:46:14 GMT 2018:INFO:Item : [0.69]
>
> Wed Mar 21 14:46:14 GMT 2018:INFO:Item : [1.6]
>
> Wed Mar 21 14:46:14 GMT 2018:INFO:Item : [3.45]
>
> Wed Mar 21 14:46:14 GMT 2018:INFO:Item : [1.85]

Comment: That looks a little complicated. I don't need to strip them all, but it would be nice to get a few. I discovered I can do this: `(//som/som) [2]` to return the 2nd occurrence of the same element.

Comment: @RobClarke Where are you extracting the values? is in the assetion script log?

Comment: I just put them into the Test Case Custom Properties, Variables that I expect to use over multiple steps in the test. I have even gone so far as to use the Conditional Goto Test Steps now and am starting to build a certain amount of flexibility and logic. The original plan was building a test suite to prove the API calls work, and expanded to check for common expected error conditions, and use it all for a bit of load testing also. But now I have built on my learning to develop some mini-routines that I can use to automate the cleanup of test data by completing transactions.